# Constantinople gas change, reentrancy possibilities

Tags: contract-design, forks, reentrant-attacks, constantinople

With the new reduced fee for using SSTORE for 'dirty' storage slots, is it possible to re-enter a function from a send() or transfer() and have the contract call send() or transfer() again?

Or is it only possible to re-enter and write to storage a few times?

In other words, does send() or transfer() revert when < 2300 gas remains in the current transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the plan is to release Constantinople without adjusting the SSTORE pricing precisely because it would be possible to re-enter (with a budget of 2,300 gas) and accomplish some of the lower-cost repriced storage operations. That would be bad for some contracts already on the chain.

`.send` and `.transfer` do indeed revert from running out gas if they are chained together.

Always use checks, effects, interactions patterns to make re-entrance safe functions to help ensure your deployed contracts are not among those that could be effected by future protocol changes.

Hope it helps.